# Is there a way to format node-sass css output?

Tags: css, npm, sass, node-sass

I'm having some trouble using node-sass for compiling my scss into css in particular - formatting. The last bracket seems unconventional and ideally would trail to the next line.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 718px; } }
```

Please see picture - [node-sass output picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXieY.png)

I have set up the build-css script to compile as so:

```
node-sass --include-path scss src/scss/main.scss dist/css/main.css
```

I'm relativley new to npm and tried to use prettier but having no luck. 
I have also tried using   --linefeed but not sure thats what I need.

**Note**
I am not using a task runner as I dont need any js in this project.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Added: 
`--output-style expanded` for a fix.